# Is there a good alternative to the CRAAP test?

Tags: research-process

I want to teach and post posters for the CRAAP test (Currency, Relevance, Authority, Accuracy, and Purpose), however, some colleagues, unfamiliar with this, aren't amused by the acronym. Is there a good alternative that is commonly used in academia, that won't make people assume this is some form of immaturity on my part?

Comment: That 'test' seems to just be one way to evaluate sources. What you likely _want_ to teach is that evaluating sources is a good thing, and here are some ways to do so. So, instead, the posters should focus on how to determine the reliability of the source, not one specific possible tool to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I laughed reading the title. Why not just switch the letters into something lile APRCA? Or something that can be read like PRACA?

Comment: This question would be improved by a link to an authoritative source on this test.

Comment: @Cell It doesn't appear this is something OP invented, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRAAP_test

Comment: It seems like the point is to draw your attention with the name

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a good alternative that is commonly used in academia,

Most of academia does not need a formal test for checking the quality of sources, so no, there is not.

> that won't make people assume this is some form of immaturity on my part?

Just leave the acronym out.  Acronyms are rarely useful and even less likely to be necessary.